# How to pass django request using pool in multiprocessing

Tags: django, pymongo

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import pymongo
import json
from bson.json_util import dumps

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["game"]
mycol = mydb["test_collection"]

def fetch_data(request):
    mycol = mydb["Eugenie_Table"]
    country = request.GET.get('country')
    qry = {'country': country}
    query =  mycol.find(qry).limit(10)
    data = json.loads(dumps(query))
    print(data)
    return data


def handle_cache(request):
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=4)
    async_result = pool.apply_async(fetch_data(request))
    return_val = async_result.get()
    print(return_val)
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Here i am using django with pymongo for fetching data from mongodb database.
Here i am getting below error.
The error is showing inside pool.

```
    TypeError at /
    'list' object is not callable
```

PLEASE HAVE A LOOK

Comment: You should pass the `args` as `args=(request,)` so a 1-tuple.

Comment: Thanks. That error is gone. I am getting another error. Please check edited question

Comment: I have edited the question with new error

Comment: please show the *full* traceback.

Comment: Thanks.bro. The error is gone after using tuple

Comment: Thanks A lot. Thanks for help